# Yii2 dynamic theme

Tags: yii2

How can I set the theme dynamically? I have a field in user profile which allows to select a theme. I have created a themes folder in @webroot and the different themes.

When the user is viewing his profile, I need to set the theme he has selected or set to default theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the property `theme` of your view component.

http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/yii-base-view.html#$theme-detail

Also this article may help

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/output-theming.md

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change themes Dynamically you can do something like that.

Function to switch themes :

```
public function actionThemeswitch($theme)
{
    $options = ['name'=>'theme','value'=>$theme,'expire'=>time()+86400*365];
    $cookie = new \yii\web\Cookie($options);
    Yii::$app->response->cookies->add($cookie);

    return $this->redirect(['backend/info']);
}
```

Create your Custom controller and extends all your controllers with below:

```
<?php
namespace frontend\components;

class Controller extends \yii\web\Controller {
    public function beforeAction($action) 
    {
        if (parent::beforeAction($action)) {
            $theme = "blue";
            if (Yii::$app->request->cookies['theme']) {
                $theme = Yii::$app->request->cookies->getValue('theme');
            }
            Yii::$app->view->theme = new \yii\base\Theme([
                'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/'.$theme],
                'baseUrl' => '@web',

            ]);
            return true;  // or false if needed
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller\abstract controller (I use abstract controller for all controllers). Also i do it in advanced Yii2, but don't think there is matter... Just change aliases you need.

```
 public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        \Yii::$app->setLayoutPath('@backend/views/theme_'.$this->getView()->themeName.'/layouts');
        $this->setViewPath($this->module->getViewPath().'/theme_'.$this->getView()->themeName.'/'.$this->id);
    }
```

`$this->getView()->themeName` is a string, in my case it's in extended View class, but you can load\store it what ever you prefer... (loads from config file)

After that in modules and base apps you should create view like that:

```
...
--views
----theme_b3
------controller1
--------action1
----------index.php
----------add.php
----------remove.php

----theme_adminLTE
------controller1
--------action1
----------index.php
----------add.php
----------remove.php
```

Main point is to create folders with theme_{themeName} ("b3","adminLTE") and store there all layouts\views we need, BUT IN OLD LOCATIONS.

So you doesn't need to create "themes" folder in root, all views will be in same locations but in sub-folders.

By the way, in this case we can switch theme easily by cookie or config, on changing from old theme to new.

PS: This solution is good if you use a lot of modules. In base app, solution from @Ravindra Bhalothia would be enough.